# Flexbox: elements collapsing - the best approach?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, padding

Consider the following:

[image: draft on a paper]

Consider this to be a full, 1920px screen. The div wrapping the texts and buttons seen in **A** is a flexbox.

When I resize the screen, the text and buttons squeeze as much as possible - as seen in **B**.

Eventually, when there's no more space to squeeze, it collapses into **C**.

Now, I've added a breakpoint so that **C** comes to effect at 1024px, meaning that the texts and buttons will have some padding between them so to never get glued together. For this, I added a `padding: 0 50px;`.

I was wondering if this - adding the padding - is the best, most efficient way of implementing this collapse given that I'm working with flexboxes.

Should this be done in a different, more appropriate way?

```css
class {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  word-wrap: normal;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  }
  @include breakpoint-max(1068px) {
    padding: 0 50px;
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Nothing wrong with using padding. But without your full code, it's hard to tell if there's a more efficient way.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `flex-wrap:wrap;`. By default it is `no-wrap`. That's why elements squeezing. You can read more here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: First off, there is no way to tell if this is what is needed, second, OP doesn't even ask why they squeeze, they ask if padding is a good way, which one again really can't answer, as no code is available, and in general being primarily opinion-based.

Comment: ```flex-wrap:wrap``` moves the element on the right to the next line, aligned to the left. I was trying to get for instance the buttons to go under each other (like on **C** on the image). I was able to fix it with a breakpoint on the buttons, adding ```display: flex``` and ```flex-direction column```. Thanks for the help though!